# indicates versions without null safety support

Tags: flutter, null-safety

I'm tryna enabled null-safe property. that's why I wrote "`dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety`" but I got error below:

***indicates versions without null safety support***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* that's an error, the message is letting you know that the *x* indicates dependencies with no null safety, while the *✓* indicates versions with null safety.

It would then normally go on to list all of your dependencies with either a *x* or a *✓*, but it doesn't because all your dependencies are null safe, so there is no need to (see the next line on your "error").